# Set priorities between mysql processes

Tags: java, mysql, grails

I'm fighting with MySQL, Grails and Java.

1. I have the app Server, with Grails app running there.
2. I have another server with mysql db.
3. I have one Java app, that connects to the server to export data in csv files.

I have a lot of data (10Million of registers) in the DB, and every 15 min the Grails app is connecting to the DB, to check and save new info. Normal way to function.

My problem is that while the grails app is working, i want to execute a java app that exports a part of the information in the db. But my problem is that the process is reaaly slow, but only sometimes. I will explain:

1. If the Grails App is working, my Java app needs around 4 days to export all the data.The Java proccess takes around 0.3-0% of CPU.
2. If I turned off the Tomcat, and consequently all the connections to the DB (show processlist command on mySQL) takes around 40 minutes
   to finish all the process. The Java proccess takes around 85% of
   CPU.

I'm not sure about what is the problem, but i tried everything, and my problem is that i can't stop the grails app all the times that i want to export. Because of this, there is some way to give priorities to the between processes to be sure that my Java app is going to have the highest priority?

Thanks in advance for your answers,

Comment: So, when Tomcat and Grails is running, your Java-based reporting program takes roughly no CPU time for 4 days? And when it's running all by itself (no Tomcat, no Grails), it runs for 40 minutes at 85% CPU time?

Comment: Yes, more or less is like this. Looks like if there are more connections to the DB in addition to my Java app, everything is really slow, and looks like has the lowest prio.

Comment: Could you clarify the data flow?  Perhaps it is `grails_app -> mysql -> java_app`?  And the mysql interaction?  `INSERT INTO table -> mysql -> SELECT * FROM table`?

Comment: Retagged the question to improve relevancy...

Comment: If you are on a *nix system you could try "nicing" the processes. `man nice` or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix) for more info.

Comment: @wallyk, the data flow is like you say. The Grails App saves the data, and the Java App exports this data. We save the info with grails methods in the DB (GORM),and we take this with a "normal" java app with JDBC connection.

Comment: @MikePurcell I'm using already nice -20 options, but nothing changes with this. Looks like this is not about system priorities, because prios inside of mysql.

Comment: @MarcoZimmerman: sounds like your reporting app is sitting around waiting for table locks or something. Obviously, it's blocking and not spinning (due to virtually no perceived CPU usage) so you're probably waiting for locks. I would check to make sure neither your Grails webapp nor your reporting app is attempting to lock way mroe than it needs to. For instance, transactions that include many tables or even issuing LOCK TABLES commands.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a database locking issue.  I'd recommend getting a tool like [innotop](https://code.google.com/p/innotop/) and taking a close look at what is happening in the database.  In particular, I'd take a careful look at open tables, locks, and queries active when your grails app is running.

Comment: Looks something like this, its true @ataylor. But my problem is that normaly the grails app is making periodic tasks each 15 min, during 5 min. But the other time, is not doing nothing, but the slow performance continues anyway.