# MySQL blocked in Preparing Statement with really strange behavior

Tags: java, mysql, query-optimization

Like I explained [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213886/set-priorities-between-mysql-processes), I had some problems with my mysql db server. I would know your opinion and have some ideas because I'm in a black hole, I don't have any idea because is happening the behavior of the server.

I will try to explain all the environment. I have 1 DB, with a lot of tables. We made a exporter tool, in java, that exports all the data from the DB. The data is stored in 5 different tables, and I need to take the data joining 5 tables. These are the tables:

The structure of the DB is a system to receive information from some sensors and store it.

Measurement table: The measurements that we receive from the sensors.

```
+--------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| version            | bigint(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| counter            | char(2)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| datemeasurement_id | datetime   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| datereal_id        | datetime   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| delayed            | bit(1)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| frequency          | tinyint(4) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| measuringentity_id | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| real               | bit(1)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tamper             | bit(1)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| value              | float      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

measuring_entity table: One sensor can measure more than one thing (Temperature, Humidity). And these are the entitys.

```
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| version      | bigint(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| household_id | varchar(4) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| operative    | bit(1)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type         | char(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| unit         | char(3)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| interval     | float      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

sensor_measuring_entity: One sensor can have more than one entity associated.

```
+--------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sensor_id          | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| measuringentity_id | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| version            | bigint(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Sensor table: The info of the sensor, related with the measuring entity in the previous table.

```
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | bigint(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| version             | bigint(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| battery             | bit(1)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| identifier          | char(6)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| installationdate_id | datetime    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| lastreceiveddate_id | datetime    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| location_id         | bigint(20)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| operative           | bit(1)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tampererror         | smallint(6) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Location table: Where is placed the sensor.

```
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| version    | bigint(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| height     | tinyint(4) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| operative  | bit(1)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| place      | char(15)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| room       | char(15)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| typesensor | char(15)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| formaster  | bit(1)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The algorithm to export the information, is a big for, like this, crossing the data, trying to export separated information for all the types of the sensor that we can have in separated csv files.:

```
for (int i = 0; i < households.length; i++) {

openConnection();

for (int j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {

    for (int k = 0; k < rooms.length; k++) {

        if (places.length > 0) {

        for (int l = 0; l < places.length; l++) {

            for (int m = 0; m < height.length; m++) {

                export(startDate2, endDate,
                    households[i], values[j],
                    rooms[k], places[l],height[m]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int m = 0; m < height.length; m++) {

                export(startDate2, endDate,
                    households[i], values[j],
                    rooms[k], null, height[m]);
            }
        }

    }
}

try {
    connection.close();
} catch (SQLException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

        }


public void export(String startTime, String endTime, String household,
        String type, String room, String place, String height)
        throws ExporterException {


    String sql = buildSQLStatement(startTime, endTime, household, type,
            room, place, height);

    Statement query;

    try {
        query = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = query.executeQuery(sql); 
        …
        (The exporting to csv code)
        …





private String buildSQLStatement(String startTime, String endTime,
        String household, String type, String room, String place,
        String height) {


    String sql = "select HIGH_PRIORITY m.datemeasurement_id, me.type, l.place, m.value, l.room, l.height, s.identifier "
            + "FROM measurement as m STRAIGHT_JOIN measuring_entity as me ON m.measuringentity_id = me.id "
            + "STRAIGHT_JOIN sensor_measuring_entity as sme ON me.id = sme.measuringentity_id "
            + "STRAIGHT_JOIN sensor as s ON sme.sensor_id = s.id "
            + "STRAIGHT_JOIN location as l ON l.id = s.location_id"
            + " WHERE m.datemeasurement_id "
            + " >"
            + "'"
            + startTime
            + "'"
            + " AND m.datemeasurement_id"
            + " <"
            + "'"
            + endTime
            + "'"
            + " AND m.measuringentity_id"
            + " IN (SELECT  me.id FROM measuring_entity AS me WHERE me.household_id="
            + "'"
            + household
            + "'"
            + ")";
```

My big problem is this: Sometimes this app with this code from the DB, works really really slow. MySQL is working really slow, and there are other times that MYSQL works really fast. We are not able to understand why is happening this difference of behavior.

For example, when it's slow (0.3-0% of CPU), it can take around 3 days to export all the data from the DB (around 200.000 querys), but like i said before, there are some moments that the server does the same work in 30-40 minutes (85% of CPU).

The problem that we saw, is that when the behavior is slow, mysql is spending a lot of time in “Preparing” state (around 140s per each query), trying to optimize the query, but like I said, this happens only some times. Not everytime.

```
1016 | root   | localhost:53936                | OptimAAL      | Query   |   10 | preparing | select HIGH_PRIORITY m.datemeasurement_id, me.type, l.place, m.value, l.room, l.height, s.identifier
```

These is one of the querys that can be executed:

```
EXPLAIN select HIGH_PRIORITY m.datemeasurement_id, me.type,
l.place,m.value, l.room, l.height, s.identifier
FROM measurement as m
STRAIGHT_JOIN measuring_entity as me ON m.measuringentity_id=me.id
STRAIGHT_JOIN sensor_measuring_entity as sme ON me.id=sme.measuringentity_id
STRAIGHT_JOIN sensor as s ON sme.sensor_id=s.id
STRAIGHT_JOIN location as l ON l.id=s.location_id
WHERE m.datemeasurement_id  >'2012-01-19 06:19:00'
AND m.datemeasurement_id <'2012-01-19 06:20:00'
AND m.measuringentity_id IN (SELECT  me.id FROM measuring_entity AS me
WHERE me.household_id='0022')
AND (height = '0')
AND (type = 'Brightness')
AND (place = 'Corner')
AND (room = 'Living room')
ORDER BY datemeasurement_id
```

This is the result of explain:

```
+----+--------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type            | possible_keys                                 | key                | key_len | ref                           | rows | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | m     | range           | FK93F2DBBC6292BE2,FK93F2DBBCA61A7F92          | FK93F2DBBC6292BE2  | 8       | NULL                          |    4 | Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | me    | eq_ref          | PRIMARY                                       | PRIMARY            | 8       | OptimAAL.m.measuringentity_id |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | sme   | ref             | PRIMARY,FK951FA3ECA61A7F92,FK951FA3ECF9AE4602 | FK951FA3ECA61A7F92 | 8       | OptimAAL.m.measuringentity_id |    1 | Using index |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | s     | eq_ref          | PRIMARY,FKCA0053BA3328FE22                    | PRIMARY            | 8       | OptimAAL.sme.sensor_id        |    1 |             |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | l     | eq_ref          | PRIMARY,place                                 | PRIMARY            | 8       | OptimAAL.s.location_id        |    1 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | me    | unique_subquery | PRIMARY,FK11C7EA07E6EB51F2                    | PRIMARY            | 8       | func                          |    1 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

Obviously, if we change the value of the date interval, the amount of data increases a lot, because we have like 1 million of measurements in our DB.

I tried everything:

Change mysQL config file (/etc/my.cnf):

```
[mysqld]
#bind-address = 141.21.8.197
max_allowed_packet = 128M
sort_buffer_size = 512M
max_connections=500
query_cache_size = 512M
query_cache_limit = 512M
query-cache-type = 2
table_cache = 80
thread_cache_size=8
key_buffer_size = 512M
read_buffer_size=64M
read_rnd_buffer_size=64M
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_buffer_pool_size=700M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=20M
datadir=/data/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
#Enable logs
log = /var/log/mysql/mysql-log.log 
log-error = /var/log/mysql/mysql-error.log  
long_query_time = 1
log-slow-queries = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

- Use different type of JOIN to force it to avoid the optimize queries.
- Use nice -20 to give the highest prio to the procces.
- Use Stored procedures instead of queries in the code.
- Close any other connections to the DB, to have the db only for me, without any other connections.
- Change and try to optimize the query.
- ...

Like you can see I tried everything, and I don't know what can I do to be sure that the server is going to be fast all the moments.

These is the info of the server:

```
MySQL version:  5.1.61-log / x86_64 
RAM: 8 GB
OS: CentOS release 6.2 (Final)
CPU: 4 Cores / Xeon E6510  @ 1.73GHz
```

I really would appreciate your help,

Edit:

I want to add that now the biggest problem for me is why happens the different behavior of the server. Because i understand that the queries can be optimized, but sometimes works really fast with this code.

My nightmare now is to know why is working fast sometimes, and not always. Now i'm checking with the IT guy if it can be some problem of hardware access, to the hard disk or something like that.

Looks also that can be a problem of the SQL configuration, or maybe the query optimizer that it has inside MYSQL, but I'm not able to discover what is the solution for my black hole.

Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a couple of optimisations you could do.

Firstly, use bind variables and a prepared statement.

```
PreparedStatment stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
"select HIGH_PRIORITY m.datemeasurement_id, me.type, l.place, m.value, l.room, l.height, s.identifier "
+ "FROM measurement as m STRAIGHT_JOIN measuring_entity as me ON m.measuringentity_id = me.id "
+ "STRAIGHT_JOIN sensor_measuring_entity as sme ON me.id = sme.measuringentity_id "
+ "STRAIGHT_JOIN sensor as s ON sme.sensor_id = s.id "
+ "STRAIGHT_JOIN location as l ON l.id = s.location_id"
+ " WHERE m.datemeasurement_id  > ? "
+ " AND m.datemeasurement_id  < ? "
+ " AND m.measuringentity_id IN (SELECT  me.id FROM measuring_entity AS me WHERE me.household_id= ? )";

stmt.setDate(1, startDate);
stmt.setDate(2, endDate);
stmt.setString(3, household);

stmt.executeQuery();
```

Secondly, remove the IN - can't you use a separate join here against measuring_entity?  IN often does not perform that well.

Thirdly, can you use batching to perform your inserts?  Batch-inserts should give you a noticeable improvement in speed.

These are a couple of things I can think of off the cuff.  All the SQL tuning in the world is not going to help if your queries are not optimized on the Java side.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. I never used until know bind variables, but i will try it.
My inserts are not the problem, because they are made separately along the time. The problem is only to extract all together. . Thanks.

Comment: I want to add that now the biggest problem for me is why happens the different behavior of the server. Because i understand that the queries can be optimized, but sometimes works really fast with this code.

My nightmare now is to know why is working fast sometimes, and not always. Now i'm checking with the IT guy if it can be some problem of hardware access, to the hard disk or something like that.

Looks also that can be a problem of the SQL configuration, or maybe the query optimizer that it has inside MYSQL, but I'm not able to discover what is the solution for my black hole.
Really Thanks

Comment: Good luck - it sounds like you have a combination of factors.  Hope you come right!

Answer (score 0):

My overall answer is, make just one query for all data and split it with java afterwards. (With almost the same code, you posted up there)

The first bottleneck is the opening of the connection for every household. 
The second depends on how big households, values, rooms, places, height arrays are. Its a bad idea to send this many queries, because the overhead for the connection is really big. You should concatenate every piece of information in one (maybe big query) and calculate how long you need to fetch the data).

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. I'm openning connection for each house because if is working in slow performance, loses the connection at some point.
And the height of the arrays is not so big. They don't have more than 30 elements.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: If your firing this queries manually, how fast did you get the results. Can you post some benchmarks results? For one query, as well as for all created queries in your java code as one run. It would be nice to know, what values do you get for duration, as for times for fetching.